# How to do ES6 imports for optimized builds?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Which of the following should I use:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

or

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

The former has the advantage of using the correct name for the component so I do not understand why I should use the latter approach to ES6 imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in this case is how the packages are arranged.

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

This one actually loads the entire bootstrap package - but it only imports the Button section to your module. The `{Button}` part can be considered destructuring only one property of a large object.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

This one only loads the Button section and the it doesn't have to do any destructuring - because, what is loaded is only the Button section.

**The second approach is better** -  because, it has to load only the code that you explicitly specify.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter of ES6. The two statements do two different things.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

This loads the file `react-bootstrap/Button.js` and returns its default export.

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

This loads the file `react-bootstrap/index.js`, and returns the `Button` export. `index.js` imports the default export from `Button.js`, and exports it as `Button` in this line:

```
export { default as Button } from './Button';
```

If this line weren't there, you would not be able to use the second form.